# Can a WTForms validator change the data being validated?

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

When validating a form, is it possible to change the data being validated?

For instance, in a form requiring the 2-letter form of a state, can the state string be capitalized? E.g., 'tx' to "TX".

Comment: you can overwrite the validation routine. http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/64/. The solution would be to perform the data manipulation using `try` and then execute the super() validation method.